# geoserver wfs access denied

Tags: geoserver

I've created a role in GeoServer called WFS_ACCESS. I've assigned it to a user called wfs_viewser and have the following rules setup:

[image]

Though when i hit my wfs service and login with wfs_viewer credentials i get an access denied error. As soon as i grant wfs_viewer "ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR" it works fine. What is wrong with my rules?

> Build Information Version
>   2.1.0 Subversion Revision 15809 Build Date 11-May-2011 20:09 GeoTools
>   Version
>   2.7.1 (rev -1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two rules don’t provide any restrictions on access by default. However, they are overridden by your third rule which specifies that the WFS_ACCESS role only has read access to data in the `catalog.*` path.

Can you post all the roles you've set?